# how do I compare these two tables?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import json
from io import StringIO
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = 'https://www.benzinga.com/premarket/'
tables = pd.read_html(url)
df = tables[5]
firstProductSet = df.iloc[: , [0]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(firstProductSet)
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
# print(df1)





PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
url = "https://thestockmarketwatch.com/markets/after-hours/trading.aspx"
driver.minimize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
SecondProductSet = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'symbol'})
secondProductSet =  SecondProductSet[0:15]
driver.quit()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(secondProductSet)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
# print (df2)


# for a in df2:
#     if df2.sort_index().sort_index(axis=1) == df1.sort_index().sort_index(axis=1):
#         print("same")
#     else:
#         print("not same")


# ne = (df1 != df2).any(1)

# df3 = df1 + df2
# df1['MatchingStocks'] = np.where(df1 == df2, 'True', 'False')
# print (df3)
```

Hey I have been trying so long, comparing these two tables (df1, df2). My goal is to print only the Stock tickers, that are in both tables (I don't need the others) I am forever thankful to the person who finds a solution to this problem

Comment: Can you post samples of `df1` and `df2` and your expected output?

Comment: have you tried do an inner join? like: `pd.merge(df, df2, 'inner', left_on='a', right_on='b')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the stocks that are common to both Series, you could use set `intersection`:

```
>>> set(df1["Stock"]).intersection(set(df2[0]))
{'ANY', 'AUPH', 'GDYN', 'GRPN', 'HCI', 'SWCH', 'WPRT'}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your response, sadly the tickers change daily, which is why i am struggling so much

Comment: @AdrianReichert - How does this stop you from running it everyday? :/

Comment: ohhhh i thought the output was part of the code, silly me :). wow it works , amazing thanks a lot

Comment: ofcourse haha, one more question do you know how i can use each ticker as a different varable ( so i can insert it into my bigger program)

Comment: You could just save the intersection to a list or set and iterate over it. You don't need different variables for each.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
products1 = pd.Series(firstproductset)
products2 = pd.Series(secondproductset)
products1[products1.isin(products2)]
```

**PS:** in the future, please make your example minimal.  All the selenium and web parsing stuff doesn't have anything to do your question.  Reduce your data to a simple case, and include that in your question.

Comment: I will do that with my next question. whith your solution this Error came up (   ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().   )   any ideas?